# Problem with section naming and Browse Application on flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I try naming a section using `flexdashboard`. But, I can not do this. I try write `HERE DOES NOT APPEAR IN DASHBOARD` as a title, but doesn't work. My code:

````
---
title: "Statistics"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: cerulean
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(flexdashboard)

set.seed(123)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(n = 6, expr = runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)

reg <- lm(
  x.1 ~ x.2 + x.3, data = df_1
)

saveRDS(object = reg, file = 'regression.rds')

out_1 <- readRDS('regression.rds')
```

Regression{data-navmenu='Forecast'}
======================================================================

Sidebar {.sidebar}
----------------------------------------------------------------------

**Panel**
```{r}

sliderInput(
  inputId = 'x.2', label = 'Advertising expenses:', 
  value = mean(df_1$x.2), min = min(df_1$x.2), max = max(df_1$x.2)
)

sliderInput(
  inputId = 'x.3', label = 'Sellers:', 
  value = mean(df_1$x.3), min = min(df_1$x.3), max = max(df_1$x.3)
)
```

```{r}

reac_1 <- reactive({
  tibble(
  x.2 = input$x.2, 
  x.3 = input$x.3
  )
})

predict_1 <- reactive({
  predict(
  out_1, reac_1()
  )
})
```

Column{}
----------------------------------------------------------------------

### HERE DOES NOT APPEARS IN DASHBOARD
```{r}

renderValueBox({
  valueBox(
  value = scales::dollar(predict_1(), prefix = 'R$ ', big.mark = '.', 
decimal.mark = ','), 
caption = ifelse(test = predict_1() < 33.3, 'Low price', 
                 ifelse(test = predict_1() < 66.6, 'Medium price', 'High price')), 
icon = ifelse(predict_1() < 33.3, 'fa-cc-visa', 
              ifelse(test = predict_1() < 66.6, 'fa-cc-mastercard', 'fa-cc-amex')), 
color = ifelse(predict_1() < 33.3, 'pink', 
               ifelse(test = predict_1() < 66.6, 'orange', 'lightgreen'))
  )
})
```

### HERE APPEARS IN DASHBOARD
```{r}
plot(reg)
```
````

The result:

[image]

How naming the section (`HERE DOES NOT APPEAR IN DASHBOARD`)?

Also, a box with `renderValueBox` is not generated when you click "Open in Browser". See:

[image]

What is blocking the `renderValueBox` from working in Browser?

Comment: Difficult to say without something I can easily reproduce on my computer. Best guess would be to strip your dashboard from all irrelevant stuff and try again. You could try and remove the curly braces behind `column`, or a least put a space between the word and braces. I remember flexdashboard being finicky about these things.

Comment: As Paul says, difficult to help without a reproducible example. It may be because you cannot have a valueBox within a titled section though.

Comment: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#value_boxes    

Notice in these examples, the headers are all interpreted as captions for each valueBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this occurs because the `renderValueBox()` strips the outer div containing your section header.

If we instead use a custom version of `renderValueBox()` that does not strip the outer div we can achieve your desired output:

````
---
title: "Statistics"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
theme: cerulean
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(flexdashboard)

# custom rendervaluebox that does not strip outer div
my_renderValueBox <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE) {
  # Convert the expression to a function
  vbox_fun <- shiny::exprToFunction(expr, env, quoted)

  # Wrap that function in another function which strips off the outer div and
  # send it to renderUI.
  shiny::renderUI({
    vbox <- vbox_fun()
    if (promises::is.promising(vbox)) {
      vbox %...>%
        { . }
    } else {
      vbox
    }
  })
}

set.seed(123)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(n = 6, expr = runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)

reg <- lm(
  x.1 ~ x.2 + x.3, data = df_1
)

saveRDS(object = reg, file = 'regression.rds')

out_1 <- readRDS('regression.rds')
```

Regression{data-navmenu='Forecast'}
======================================================================

Sidebar {.sidebar}
----------------------------------------------------------------------

**Panel**
```{r}

sliderInput(
  inputId = 'x.2', label = 'Advertising expenses:', 
  value = mean(df_1$x.2), min = min(df_1$x.2), max = max(df_1$x.2)
)

sliderInput(
  inputId = 'x.3', label = 'Sellers:', 
  value = mean(df_1$x.3), min = min(df_1$x.3), max = max(df_1$x.3)
)
```

```{r}

reac_1 <- reactive({
  tibble(
    x.2 = input$x.2, 
    x.3 = input$x.3
  )
})

predict_1 <- reactive({
  predict(
    out_1, reac_1()
  )
})
```

Column{}
----------------------------------------------------------------------

### HERE NOW APPEARS AS DESIRED
```{r}
my_renderValueBox({
  valueBox(
    value = scales::dollar(predict_1(), prefix = 'R$ ', big.mark = '.', 
                           decimal.mark = ','), 
    caption = ifelse(test = predict_1() < 33.3, 'Low price', 
                     ifelse(test = predict_1() < 66.6, 'Medium price', 'High price')), 
    icon = ifelse(predict_1() < 33.3, 'fa-cc-visa', 
                  ifelse(test = predict_1() < 66.6, 'fa-cc-mastercard', 'fa-cc-amex')), 
    color = ifelse(predict_1() < 33.3, 'pink', 
                   ifelse(test = predict_1() < 66.6, 'orange', 'lightgreen'))
  )
})
```

### HERE APPEARS IN DASHBOARD
```{r}
plot(reg)
```
````

[image: dashboard]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you are experiencing in your browser, but I suspect that may be a browser specific issue. The above works fine for me in RStudio, Firefox v69.0b7, and Chrome v75.0.3770.142.